# ESS R: how to get TAB-completion when editing .R-files?

Tags: completion, ess, r

When editing an .R-file I see that `ess-r-mode` is on ("ESS[R]" in the status line). If an R session is opened in another buffer, I see that `inferior-ess-r-mode` is on there ("iESS [R:1]").

In the R-session buffer I see that there's TAB completion: it completes a string with possible function/variable names, and within a function's parentheses it gives list of arguments. That's very convenient. In the .R-file buffer, on the other hand, this doesn't happen.

Is it possible to have this kind of completion in the buffer editing the .R-file, that is, in `ess-r-mode`?

I see that `ess-use-company` and `ess-use-eldoc` are both `t`, at their standard values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, `ess-r-mode` doesn't provide completion *until* it's associated with an R process. This is because "In R versions newer than 2.14.1, ESS uses R's built-in completion engine" [ESS Manual](https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Function-arguments). Which means there's nothing to complete without an R process connected.

I don't think there's a way to automatically attach a script buffer to an R process - ESS would have to know if you wanted multiple scripts to share the same process, or to each get their own process, or some combination.

My work-around: in practice, I usually want to run code from my script as soon as I open it (such as loading packages or data), which means completion is available as soon as I do. If I want completion *before* I've written any code at all, I will usually just send a `ls()` to get R started, and then work from there.

### Update:

Another work around is to automatically call `ess-switch-process` (i.e., `C-c C-s`) when you open a file in r-mode, the following code in your init should do it:

```lisp
(add-hook 'ess-r-mode-hook 'my-start-r-process)

(defun my-start-r-process ()
  (ess-switch-process))
```

or even just the single line:

```lisp
(add-hook 'ess-r-mode-hook 'ess-switch-process)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and work-around! I think I can just write a macro to call `C-c C-s` directly after the R session is started; or something to that effect.

Comment: @pglpm I misunderstood what you meant. You can use a hook to call `C-c C-s`, I'll update the answer

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried, ess-r-mode do have completion.
Maybe check the value of company-backends. I have 
(company-R-library company-R-args company-R-objects :separate) in it, did not need to set it myself though.

Comment: Thank you Sean. I discovered that completion gets activated if I "attach" the file-buffer with an R session, with `C-c C-s`. I'm trying to understand whether the attachment can be done automatically.

But maybe with `company` I don't need to do this.